# How to not hide a taxonomy term if it has no content

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a view that shows content. The issue is that I needed to still show a taxonomy term even if it has no content under it. Is that possible?

[Here's the screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0AqcKgEkHoRMkpXdllzQnM3eEE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Is this a Term view or Content view? Are you using grouping? Rather than the screenshot the views export code might help better.

Comment: +1 to remove -1, who's done a -1 without mentioning the reason in a comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add output to be displayed even if the taxonomy term has no content related to it by adding a field under the settings "No results behavior".

Try adding "Global: Unfiltered text" and add the text that should display when there is no content assigned to the term.